# iOSデバイスの姿勢を角度で取得したい

Tags: swift, ios

iOSデバイスの姿勢を、ジャイロから取得したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

調べてみたところ、
http://qiita.com/yimajo/items/49bd534e8c257294a2e3
この記事が私の求めることに最も近いのですが、記事が書かれた時期が古いので参考にできません...。

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmattitude
APIリファレンスも見てみましたが、いまいち何をどうすればroll、pitch、yawが取得できるのか分かりません！

アドバイスを頂けると助かりますよろしくお願いします。

また、別の質問になりますが、iOSデバイスの位置はGPSで、姿勢はジャイロから求めることができると思いますが、デバイスの存在する高さを取得することは出来ないのでしょうか？
合わせて回答していただけるとうれしいです。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！独立している別々の質問は、別々に質問してくださると嬉しいです。この質問を見ている人が同時に回答してくださることを期待しているのでしたら、関連する質問としてリンクを貼ると良いかもしれません。自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」から自由に編集できますので、お試しください。

Answer (score 2):

古い情報だから、参考にならないというのは、ちょっと乱暴すぎますね。そうやって、得られる情報源を狭めてしまうことで、不利益になるのは、質問者さん自身であることに、ぜひ気づいていただきたいものです。リンク先の情報の、CoreMotionフレームワークに関する解説は、まったく古くはなっておらず、じつにためになるものだと思いますよ。

---

とりあえず、リンク先にある、Objective-Cのサンプルコードを、Swift3に移植したものを、載せておきます。コピー＆ペーストで、そのまま実機にインストール可能な状態にしてあります。

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pitchLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rollLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yawLabel: UILabel!

    var motionManager: CMMotionManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        motionManager?.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0
    }

    @IBAction func getAttitude(_ sender: Any) {
        attitude()
    }

    func attitude() {
        guard let _ = motionManager?.isDeviceMotionAvailable,
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue.current
        else {
            return
        }

        motionManager?.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: operationQueue, withHandler: { motion, _ in
            if let attitude = motion?.attitude {
                self.pitchLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f", attitude.pitch * 180.0 / Double.pi)
                self.rollLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f", attitude.roll * 180.0 / Double.pi)
                self.yawLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f", attitude.yaw * 180.0 / Double.pi)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

※Objective-Cに関する知識と経験よりむしろ、Swiftによるプログラミングの経験値を上げていけば、移植はたいしてむずかしくないのではないでしょうか？

---

> デバイスの存在する高さを取得することは出来ないのでしょうか？

GPSで、取得できるはずです。私も詳しくはないので、これ以上の説明は控えさせてもらいますが、これも、情報源をえり好みさえしなければ、日本語の情報を見つけることができるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: Objective-Cが全くわからないもので...。

Comment: ありがとうございましたたたたた